# Empty value in activeadmin for checkboxes list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I use checkboxes list for enum to select multiple values in activeadmin:

```
c.input :weekdays, as: :check_boxes, collection: BusinessHour.weekdays.keys
```

For some reason there is hidden value added:

```
<input type="hidden" name="listing[listing_prices_attributes][0][weekdays][]" id="listing[listing_prices_attributes][0]_weekdays_none" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

So when form is submitted it actually adds also empty value "" in array and makes problem.

Tried also add include_hidden: false, include_blank: false but it also doesn't change empty string value.

Any reason why it works this way?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and I resolve it like this:
In my case, I have Service and Subscription models.  I have nested attributes for subscription in the service edit form. I filtered the request params and call super then.

```
controller do
    def update
      check_locations = params[:service][:subscription_attributes][:check_locations].reject(&:empty?)
      params[:service][:subscription_attributes][:check_locations] = check_locations
      super
    end

    def create
      check_locations = params[:service][:subscription_attributes][:check_locations].reject(&:empty?)
      params[:service][:subscription_attributes][:check_locations] = check_locations
      super
    end
  end
```